# Identify what program queried specific domain/IP Address

Tags: windows, windows-10, dns

I recently started logging DNS queries and noticed that one of my Windows 10 computers is constantly querying bitstamp.com

www.bitstamp.net     09-20 19:03:15     IPv4    192.168.1.147

How can I track down which process/program is making this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a command prompt as administrator and run `netstat -b`. You could also try [TCPView](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) or [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)

Comment: Sorry forgot to mark as answer